# JavaScript Array Accessing elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm fairly new to Javascript, what I am trying to do is work out how to setup the correct array style for my form. What I want to be able to do is add each schedule to an array as a string and then be able to access the elements of that string(s) later for use such as sorting or searching for in the string. Currently its accessing each word as an index not a string first, the correct way to access an element within a string would be as myArray[0] = the string and then myArray[0][0] = the first element of that string and so on and so forth? I'd like to use vanilla Javascript as im still learning the fundamentals. Below is my code for how i am adding each schedule to the array, Im not sure where im going wrong, I think it has to do with the way its getting added to the global array. Thanks guys.

```
    var myArr = new Array();

    function addSchedule() {
    var myPriority;
    var date;
    var endtime;
    var mySubject;


if(document.getElementById('high').checked){
    myPriority = document.getElementById('high').value;

}else if(document.getElementById('low').checked)    {                
    myPriority  = document.getElementById('low').value;
}

    date = document.getElementById('Date').value;
    endtime = document.getElementById('endtime').value;
    mySubject = document.getElementById('Subject').value;

var priorityString = (myPriority)
var dateString = (date)
var subjectString = (mySubject)

// I think this needs to be a string some how but i dont know
var oneString = new   Array(priorityString,dateString,endTimeString,subjectString)

myArr[myArr.length] = (oneString)
```

Comment: Have you tried using objects instead?

Comment: Could you show me what you mean?

Comment: var o = {priority:[1, 2, 3], date:[], end:[], subject:[]}; o.priority will give you the array of numbers.

Comment: Is there a more simpler, most likely dumber way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're actually trying to do is add *objects* to an array which represent each of the properties you're reading from your UI

```
var myArr = new Array();

function addSchedule() {
    var myPriority;
    var date;
    var endtime;
    var mySubject;    

    if(document.getElementById('high').checked){
        myPriority = document.getElementById('high').value;
    }else if(document.getElementById('low').checked)    {                
        myPriority  = document.getElementById('low').value;
    }

    date = document.getElementById('Date').value;
    endtime = document.getElementById('endtime').value;
    mySubject = document.getElementById('Subject').value;

    // create an object
    var myObj = {
       priority: myPriority,
       date : date,
       endTime: endtime,
       subject: mySubject
    };
    // add it to array
    myArr.push(myObj);
}
```

Thereafter, if you wanted to read an object & it's properties from the array you could have

```
// for example:
var firstObjectPriority = myArr[0].priority;
```

Comment: Thanks for the repy, is there another way to do it besides objects? like just pushing through a string I know it may  be cumber-stone method but im trying to find another way ha sorry man

Comment: Another way to do *what* its not entirely clear what you want to do. (Also, [cumbersome](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cumbersome&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=qM0gVsPnMMG5ac7wlMgN), not cumber-stone :))